# Apache Header cache control using Location

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, http-headers

I am trying to set two different http headers for cache control for two different portions of our site.

These are the lines in my site.conf for the virtual host:

```
<Location ~ "^/(sub1|sub2|sub3|sub4)">
Header set Cache-Control max-age=60,public
</Location>
```

and

```
<Location ~ "^/(sub5|sub6|sub7|sub8)">
Header set Cache-Control no-cache
</Location>
```

I can see the headers set correctly for the first set of sub pages, but not for the second set.

I feel like I am missing something very small and obvious.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

KM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out -- removed the quotes around the expression and the cache controls are being set correctly. Hopefully, this is helpful.